# Load an external file in a grunt-contrib-jade task

Tags: gruntjs

So I've got this grunt-contrib-jade setup that is working just fine

Everything is fine when I include my data in the (exported) Gruntfile myself:

```
module.exports = {
   website: {
     options: {
       data: {
         pageTitle: "This is my website",
         greeting: "Hello world",
       },
       debug: true,
       pretty: true
    },
    files: {
      'build/website/index.html': 'src/jade/template/index.jade'
    }
  }
};
```

It merges my index.jade with my data values and my index.html output is the way it should be. But when I want to load an external file to define my data it goes wrong:

```
options: {
  data: function (dest, src) {
    // Return an object of data to pass to templates
    return require('src/jade/template/locals.json');
  },
  debug: true,
  pretty: true
},
files: {
  'build/website/index.html': 'src/jade/template/index.jade'
}
```

The require path is valid, I triple checked it. It's located in the same folder as my index.jade. However I still keep getting this error:

```
Running "jade:website" (jade) task
>> Jade failed to compile "src/jade/template/index.jade".
>> Error: Cannot find module './locals.json'
>> Destination not written because compiled files were empty.
```

I tried just about everything, but I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local modules need to be prepended with './' when you `require` them.

```
  data: function (dest, src) {
    // Return an object of data to pass to templates
    return require('./src/jade/template/locals.json');
  }
```

will work. You're not doing anything with the function (at least yet), so this could also be

`data: require('./src/jade/template/locals.json')`

or even

`data: grunt.file.readJSON('./src/jade/template/locals.json')`.

Comment: I've tried all these things before, good answers, because I thought it'd work like this. But still I keep getting te following error:

➜  template git:(master) ✗ grunt watch
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module './src/jade/template/locals.json'
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: What's the output when you run grunt with the `--verbose` flag? What does your `watch` task look like?

Comment: great, your questions got me on the right 'path' (if you pardon the pun). I used an modular setup for grunt based on https://github.com/chriscoyier/My-Grunt-Boilerplate. It turns out that the path was relative to the file itself, but somehow my brain was still thinking the path was relative to the Gruntfile that loads the task.js file. All I got to do is figuring out if something like ../../ is possible now. Thanks a lot max!